# Update matching object values

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. I have `oldPrice` and `newPrice` variable with some data. Then I have added them together in a single list called- `allItems`. Now you will notice in both variable `oldPrice` and `newPrice` having ASIN property which is identity of each data set. Now my goal is-  in `allItems` variable I want matching ASIN value data `price` should be updated. Like- `ASIN = “one”, ASIN = “two”` are common in both `newPrice` and `oldPrice` so from `newPrice` to `oldPrice` should be updated in `one and two`. How can I do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASIN_REFRESH_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test App");

            //old price has 4 values
            var oldPrice = new List<ThirdPartyData>();
            oldPrice.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "one", price = 5, IsPrime = true });
            oldPrice.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "two", price = 6, IsPrime = true });
            oldPrice.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "three", price = 7, IsPrime = false });
            oldPrice.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "four", price = 8, IsPrime = false });

            //new price has 2 values
            var newPrices = new List<ThirdPartyData>();
            newPrices.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "one", price = 1, IsPrime = false });
            newPrices.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "two", price = 2, IsPrime = true });

            var allItems = new List<ThirdPartyData>();//here old price and new price added in single list
            allItems.AddRange(newPrices);
            allItems.AddRange(oldPrice);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class ThirdPartyData
    {
        public string ASIN { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have old and new prices lists - use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is not clear (at least for me), but here it is how you can get started with updating a list based on another list:

```
oldPriceMap = oldPrice.ToDictionary(p => p.ASIN, p => p);
foreach (var item in allItems) {
    if (oldPriceMap.Cotains(item.ASIN)) {
        // change something on current item
        item.price = oldPrice.price;
    }
}
```

Why the map? Your example has very small lists, but what if the old list is quite large (thousands of items)? You have to lookup for a match and this takes O(n) in a regular list. The map helps in reducing this to O(1).

Comment: i am having thousands of data. My question is i want allItems var with updated price only which i set in newprice. can u tell me how can i get allItems var with updated price only?

Comment: @johnCogdle Take the example @Alexei provided and just update the `price` property instead of the `ASIN` property.